Yukawa Theory with Spinor-Helicity Formalism
I am trying to learn spinor-helicity formalism, and I am attempting to calculate the all-minus amplitude of 4-fermion scattering at tree level in Yukawa theory, but I have no way to check if my derivation is correct. I am using this text: Scattering Amplitudes in Gauge Theory and Gravity namely exercise 2.6. The diagram for the process is

If I take all of the fermions (and anti-fermions) to have all minus helicities, then my amplitude is
\begin{align}
i\mathcal{A} & = (-ig)^2\overline{u}(p_4)v(p_3)\frac{-i}{(p_1+p_2)^2}\overline{u}(p_2)v(p_1)\\
& = ig^2\frac{\langle 43\rangle \langle 21\rangle}{\langle 12\rangle [12]}\\
& = ig^2\frac{\langle 43\rangle}{[12]}
\end{align}
where I used $(p+q)^2 = \langle pq\rangle [pq]$. My main question are then:

is this result correct (like is this it?).

This is only the $s$-channel, but do I need to include the $t$- and $u$-channel diagrams? How do I know whenever to include those other channels, like what line of reasoning gets me there? (If there are more diagrams I'll update this post to include them so I can have a total amplitude and then derive the square of the amplitude).


Note: the formalism being used for the spinors is that everything is outgoing.
